# Bibliography string 'inlang' untranslated(biblatex) error BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

This error is apearing when trying to compile my document:

> Bibliography string 'inlang' untranslated(biblatex)                at entry 'noauthor_list_2021' on input line 19.

MWE:

main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@misc{noauthor_list_2021,
    title = {List of numeral systems},
    copyright = {Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License},
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_numeral_systems&oldid=1025510791},
    abstract = {This is a list of numeral systems, that is, writing systems for expressing numbers.},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2021-06-01},
    journal = {Wikipedia},
    month = may,
    year = {2021},
    note = {Page Version ID: 1025510791},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chicago-authordate,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
    There is hundreds of numeral systems\cite{noauthor_list_2021}.

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nobody can compile this to test your issue. Make a small, complete and selfcontained example.

Comment: I edited the original question :-)

Comment: hm, it errors for me. the style seems to use a undefined command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading biblatex-chicago in the wrong way. It should be loaded as package. If you only set the style, needed bits are missing. I would recommend to switch to the biber backend.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=bibtex,sorting=nty]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
    There is hundreds of numeral systems\cite{noauthor_list_2021}.

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```